# Count the number of each character type and display the results as a bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use the Ascii character set to count the number of each character type for 'pride-and-prejudice.txt' and display the results as a bar graph.

Here is the code provided by my tutor.

```
Max_ascii = 127
Min_ascii = 32
a_place = 97
z_place = 122
file = open('pride-and-prejudice.txt')
training = file.read()
int_text = []
maxchars = len(training)
int_text = np.zeros(maxchars)
i = 0
for letter in training:
    ascii_val = ord(letter)
    if (ascii_val >= Min_ascii) and (ascii_val <= Max_ascii):
        int_text[i] = ascii_val
        i+=1

counts = np.zeros(Max_ascii-Min_ascii+1)
num_chars = len(counts)
ascii_vals = np.arange(Min_ascii,Max_ascii+1,1)
i=0
for val in ascii_vals:
    counts[i] = np.sum(int_text==val)
    i+=1

plt.bar(np.arange(1,z_place-a_place+2,1),counts[a_place-Min_ascii:z_place-Max_ascii])
plt.show()
```

My question is what's meaning of this code?

```
counts[a_place-Min_ascii:z_place-Max_ascii]
```

I know it does counting the character from A to Z, but why it should be writtern '[a_place-Min_ascii:z_place-Max_ascii]'? Why does 'counts[a_place:z_place]' not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have no idea what your tutor is on about, but i will say that he/she has an... *interesting* coding style.

let me show you something. all except the last 2 lines of your tutor's could be re-written to look something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

with open('pride_and_predjudice.txt') as f:
    chars = Counter(char for line in f for char in line.lower())

chars = {char: chars[char] for char in ascii_lowercase}
```

at this point, `chars` contains an alphabetically ordered dict (assuming you're using python 3.6+) with counts of all the (lowercase) letters. and you should be able to do something like the below to display it:

```
plt.bar(np.arange(len(chars)), np.array(chars.values()))
plt.show()
```

play around with this and see if you have some success. good luck.

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you!